# gitk - don't show labels for branches that don't match glob or regexp

Tags: git, gitk

I'm in a huge repo with lots of committers and branches all over.
I use gitk to visualize history and normally I limit the output using `--glob=*IDENTIFIER*`.
However, if there are some branches pointing to commits that are in the filtered view - they are sill shown (even if their name doesn't include IDENTIFIER at all).
**Is there a way to not show them?**

### Example

GitHub repo for screenshots: https://github.com/chhh/too-many-labels-in-gitk

I want to see only branch labels (remote or local) that have **feature** in them.
`gitk --simplify-by-decoration --all` sample simplified view of the repo:

[image: simplified view of the repo gitk --all --simplify-by-decoration]

I want to see just the **feature** branches.

`gitk --simplify-by-decoration --glob=*feature/*`

[image]

It's better, leaf branches such as `garbage/11` at the top is gone now. But all the clutter from intermediate `garbage` and `experiment` branches is still visible I only want to see labels that start with `feature/`, i.e. remove the ones that are marked red in the next screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @SajibKhan 1) This is not a gitk solution (you need to do the filtering through git log, not grep) 2) This has the exact same result as `gitk --glob=*feature/*` - non-matching leaf branches are gone, but the extra branch names in what's printed are still present

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `gitk` takes the exact same options as `git log`, so you can check `git log`'s documentation.

Try : `--decorate-refs=<pattern>`

Comment: Yes, gitk does take the same options as git log. You can use `--decorate-refs-exclude=<pattern>` to remove the "labels" from git log output. However, this does not affect gitk. Gitk will still paint those green/orange branch labels on every commit that has a ref.